# Unknown column error when joining from 2 different databases

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble building my query, I'm getting an error on Unknown Column, j.id in on clause.

Here's my query so far

```
SELECT 
    j.id,
    j.title,
    venues.name as venueName,
    ja.completed
FROM
    dbsivcmsnew.jobs AS j, 
    venues
LEFT JOIN dbsiv.job_applications AS ja ON ja.jobId = j.id
WHERE 
    j.venueId = venues.id 
    AND j.closingDate > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
    AND j.active = 1
ORDER BY 
    j.closingDate DESC
```

From what I can see from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13703501/993600) the syntax is correct.

However, the JOIN might be unnecessary, what my query will need to return is

```
SELECT 
    j.id,
    j.title,
    venues.name as venueName,
    ja.completed
FROM
    jobs AS j, 
    venues,
    dbsiv.job_applications AS ja
WHERE 
    j.venueId = venues.id 
    AND j.closingDate > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
    AND j.active = 1
    AND ja.pin = $CurrentUsersId //This needs to optional though, if no match ja.completed should be 0
ORDER BY 
    j.closingDate DESC
```

Is it possible to make that WHERE statement optional without using a join?

Comment: Even if you do not explicitly use the JOIN keyword, you are, in fact, using (INNER) joins in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you'r mixing syntaxes for "table joining", which is... not a good idea

Just add your additional clause in the LEFT JOIN should do the trick

```
SELECT 
    j.id,
    j.title,
    v.name as venueName,
    ja.completed
FROM
    jobs j
inner join venues v on v.id = j.venueID
left join dbsiv.job_applications ja on ja.jobId = j.id and ja.pin = $CurrentUsersId
WHERE 

    AND j.closingDate > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
    AND j.active = 1
ORDER BY 
    j.closingDate DESC
```

Comment: Thanks :), I never even thought about that venue clause. (I'll accept when SO lets me)

Answer (score 0):

Change your select to:

```
SELECT 
    j.id,
    j.title,
    venues.name as venueName,
    ja.completed
FROM
    dbsivcmsnew.jobs AS j join  j.venueId = venues.id 
    venues on 
LEFT JOIN dbsiv.job_applications AS ja ON ja.jobId = j.id
WHERE 
    j.closingDate > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
    AND j.active = 1
ORDER BY 
    j.closingDate DESC
```

If you use join, than use it for all tables in from statement

Answer (score 0):

Column j.id was not accessible in join condition because of the order in which you specified the INNER JOIN. I have rearranged the order, as below:

```
SELECT 
    j.id,
    j.title,
    venues.name as venueName,
    ja.completed
FROM    
    VENUES
INNER JOIN dbsivcmsnew.jobs AS j ON j.venueId = venues.id
LEFT JOIN dbsiv.job_applications AS ja ON ja.jobId = j.id
WHERE j.closingDate > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
AND j.active = 1
ORDER BY J.CLOSINGDATE DESC;
```