# How to run a query with a join accross two databases with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got two PDO objects representing two databaes, pdo1 and pdo2, declared as per the following:

```
try {
    $pdo1 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database1', 'user', 'password');
    $pdo1->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo1->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
}
```

^ And I've done the same for $pdo2 which is for the second database.

The way I've been accessing the database so far has been like the following:

```
try {
     $sql   = 'SELECT * from table1';
     $result = $pdo1->query($sql);  
}
```

Now I want to run a query where two tables are joined across two databases. How can I do this with the two pdo objects? Here's what I've got, but I'm stuck on how to do the $result part where I've put asterixis:

```
try {
     $sql   = 'SELECT database1.table1.name FROM database1.table1 LEFT JOIN database2.table2
               ON database1.table1.userid = database2.table2.userid';
     $result = $pdo***->query($sql);    
     }
```

Previously, it would refer to either $pdo1 or $pdo2, but how do you combine that part to pull the result from combined pdo objects?

Comment: You must be able to join two tables accross two databases some way using pdo, no?

Comment: You can, but you must use a single PDO object with a user that has access to both databases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php sql join together multiple tables from different databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703337/php-sql-join-together-multiple-tables-from-different-databases)

Comment: The user has access to both databases. But how do I declare the PDO object to represent both databases in that case?

Comment: You don't. Just declare one in the connection string, and use db prefixes as you have done in your example.

Comment: I did see that question already, but I am still unclear about to do: $result = $pdo(which one?) ->query($sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *one* connection, then do a query like

```
SELECT ... FROM db1.tbl1 JOIN db2.tbl2 ...
```

(You will need permissions to access both databases.)