# PHP - Left join from two tables in different databases with different credentials using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

***Please note:** While my original issue was not possible to be solved in the way I expected, @Bamar solution marked in this post is an alternative that reaches the same goal and works perfectly. What I proposed in this post to be done doesn't seem to be viable if the databases are located in different hosts.*

I've been searching for a while and I seem to be unable to solve my issue.

### THE DATA I HAVE

My service provider is 1&1. In the current contract I have with them I could create up to 100 databases with a maximun size of 2GB each.
Each database that is created, is assingned a random hostname, port and username (the only item which I can choose is the password).
I've got two different databases, lets call them **DB_1** and **DB_2**.
In the **DB_1** I've got a table called **T_USERS** which fields of interest for this particular problem are:

- **ID**: The ID of the record.
- **userName**: The user name registered on the database.

In the **DB_2** I've got a table called **T_SCORES** which fields of interest for this particular problem are:

- **ID_User**: it's a foregin key that refers to the ID of a particular user in **DB_1.T_USERS**
- **score**: a numeric value that indicates the score of that user.

*It is important to take into account that to access both databases each of them needs different credentials!*

### WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE

What I want to achieve seems simple at a first glance but I was unable to find any documentation or solution online on how to do this using PHP and PDO.
I just want to perform a join with DB_2.ID_USER and DB_1.ID
My final result should look something like this:

| DB_1.userName | DB_2.score |
| --- | --- |
| Alex | 237 |
| Peter | 120 |
| Mark | 400 |
| ... | ... |

### WHERE I'M CURRENTLY STUCK

This is what I've currently tried.
First of all I perform the connection to my databases as follows (I normally use a try/catch when connecting to a DB but I will omit it here):

```
//Connection to the DB1
$db1_hostName = "hostnameofDB1";//The host name of the database 1
$db1_name = "db1";//The name of the database 1
$db1_userName = "user1";//The username in the database 1
$db1_password = "pw1";//The password for the database 1
$pdo_db1Handle = new PDO("mysql:host=$db1_hostName; dbname=$db1_name;", $db1_userName, $db1_password);
$pdo_db1Handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//Connection to the DB2
$db2_hostName = "hostnameofDB2";//The host name of the database 2
$db2_name = "db2";//The name of the database 2
$db2_userName = "user2";//The username in the database 2
$db2_password = "pw2";//The password for the database 2
$pdo_db2Handle = new PDO("mysql:host=$db2_hostName; dbname=$db2_name;", $db2_userName, $db2_password);
$pdo_db2Handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

So basically up to this point what I've done is very simple, create a pdo_db1Handle and pdo_db2Handle. Now to the tricky part...
If I now want to perform a join my SQL syntax should be something like this:

```
SELECT DB_1.T_USERS.userName, DB_2.T_SCORES.score
FROM DB_2.T_SCORES 
    LEFT JOIN DB_1.T_USERS 
    ON (DB_2.T_SCORES.ID_User=DB_1.T_USERS.ID)
ORDER BY DB_2.T_SCORES.score ASC 'The ordering is optional, I'm interested in the join part first
```

But as far as I'm aware and with all the information I was able to find, you execute the SQL statement against one of the two handles I previously defined in the following way:

```
$stmt=$pdo_db1Handle->prepare($mySQLStatement);
$stmt->execute();
```

When I try to do this, an error shows up telling me missing credentials for the DB_2. It happens the opposite (missing credentials of DB_1) if I try to execute it against pdo_db2Handle.
How should I proceed? any solution using PDO for this?

***Thanks in advance :)***

Comment: Well firstly you'd need a user loaded into your PDO who can simultaneously access both databases. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053648/how-to-run-a-query-with-a-join-accross-two-databases-with-pdo) Further, for your PDO connection simply omit defining the database.

Comment: You can't join between different connections in SQL. You'll need to code it in PHP using nested loops.

Comment: @Martin You can join between databases in a single connection, but he needs two connections because of the permission differences.

Comment: no it is not bad design and you can't use two different connections to different servers for that in pdo

Comment: @Barmar: Different database don't means different server instance. I often work with sql server and make query on different databases.

Comment: @DonKnacki But in his application they are different server instances. `hostnameofDB1` vs `hostnameofDB2`

Comment: As @Barmar says, for clarification, it is a different server instance.
This is a service provided by 1&1 where each database seems to be located in a different host.

Comment: @Barmar: yes you are right, I didn't pay attention to this

Comment: @AlexIbrahimOjea Why do you have different hostnames if they're the same server? But it doesn't really matter -- you can't join if the user doesn't have access to both databases.

Comment: @Barmar I have no control as how the databases are created. This is something already provided by 1&1.
I do have the credentials for both databases, but they are different for each of them (as well as the hostname)

Comment: They're NOT the same. `$db1_hostName = "hostnameofDB1";` vs `$db2_hostName = "hostnameofDB2";`

Comment: @Barmar yes I took OPs comment that's now deleted.

Comment: @Barmar I've edited the post at the begining adding a clarification on how the databases are created to avoid confussion to other users and why they are generated in different hostnames. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't join if you have to use separate PDO connections, so use nested loops and join the data in PHP.

```
$stmt_user = $pdo_db1Handle->query("SELECT id, username FROM t_users");
$stmt_score = $pdo_db2Handle->prepare("SELECT score FROM t_scores WHERE id_user = :userid");

$results = [];
while ($row_user = $stmt_user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $scores = [];
    $stmt_score->execute(':userid' => $row_user['id']);
    while ($row_score = $stmt_score->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $scores[] = $row_score['score'];
    }
    $results[$row_user['username']] = $scores;
}
```

This will create an associative array whose keys are usernames and values are an array of their scores.

Comment: I've tried your solution and it works, however, please take into account that you made a mistake:
$scores[] = $row['score']; should be: $scores[] = $row_score['score'];
Otherwise it will return NULL and I actually took a while to figure out what was wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, a work around may be to [copy the table from one database to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832260/how-to-copy-table-from-one-table-on-remote-server-to-table-on-a-different-remote) temporarily and the perform your sql once you have both tables in a single database:

```sql
$pdo1 = new PDO('mysql:host=$db1_hostName; dbname=$db1_name', $db1_userName, $db1_password);
$pdo2 = new PDO('mysql:host=$db2_hostName; dbname=$db1_name', $db2_userName, $db2_password);

$insert_stmt = $pdo2->prepare("INSERT INTO T_SCORES (col1, col2, col3, ...) VALUES (:col1, :col2, :col3, ...) ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE");
$select_results = $pdo1->query("SELECT * FROM T_SCORES");
while ($row = $select_results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $insert_stmt->execute($row);
}

-- now work with the tables as you usually would.
```

You can create the table in the target database before hand and truncate the data before and/or after performing the insert.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your feedback.
Actually @Barmar solution works like a charm and there is no need of duplicating values from one database to another, which can be dangerous.

Comment: "Dangerous" is subjective. Domain Driven Development and plenty of enterprise patterns use data copying and synchronization, eg ETL. That said there are pros and cons to each solution. @Barmar's solution will work fine for very small tables but efficiency in memory and CPU usage can soon come into play. The database server has its own resources and will perform this task quicker. Then there is the issue of more complex code needed if your pattern changes and syncing PHP logic with DB schema.

Comment: As you mentioned @Bamar solution requires an extra workload of managing the array and it won't be suitable for large datasets.
For my scenario whoever is more than enough since I will paginate the results of the scores (for example just show 20 per page or something like that).
My terminology of "dangerous" refers to the fact that you are copying data to a table for a user's query and that you need a way to handle multiple temp tables per user and also a way to handle the drop of those created temp tables.

Comment: Use cases are specific. Truncated the table and refreshing on regular interval maybe an option. Once you bring in things like paging or joining for additional columns/rows the php based solution may become unwieldy. My assumption was once copied from a to b, you can perform everything in sql, including paging. You'll work out what is best for use case.